# Importing svn repositories from Origo

Tags: svn, import, export, dump, svnadmin

Origo is shutting down their SVN hosting, so I am once again forced to move to another SVN hosting service. The thing is, they did provide us with an URL to a "nightly dump" of the repository.

But in fact, this is NOT a Subversion **portable dump** file. What I got is a 280Mb "tar.gz" backup of the whole filesystem repository.

Thus, when trying to "import" or manage that backup I am faced with a few issues.

1. It was created with any version of svnadmin that I don't know about
2. It was created on linux (it seems), and I am working on Windows

Since I am planning to go back to Assembla for SVN hosting, I need a valid **portable dump** file for import. Here is where I am stuck:

- I cannot do a `svnadmin load` because I did not get a valid dump file in the first place.
- I tried to untar/unzip the backup file to a folder, then create myself a dump using `svnadmin dump`. But then I get a dreaded message: 'vnadmin: E160033: Unknown FS type 'fsfs

  - Note the weird message: s has been replaced by '
  - If you look closely you will find that this is the result of printing Unknown FS type '%s' with %s=fsfs\cr...
  - So, I **do have** a **CR+LF** issue with that backup. Which I confirmed by comparing a fresh `svnadmin create testrepo` against my Origo repository.

I am posting a question here hoping that I can find a way to kinda handle this conversion from a linux svn repository to a windows svn repository.

I already see two options out of this mess, both of which I would **rather try to avoid**:

**OPTION 1**: Use a linux PC. That means:

1. Find a linux PC
2. untar/unzip there
3. install svn.
4. use svnadmin to create a **portable dump** (in the hopes that whatever svnadmin I end-up using is still compatible with the repo I got in the first place).

**OPTION 2**: Use svnsync

1. Install svn, including `svnsync`
2. Use it on the original repository to sync and create a mirrored repository
3. Use `svndump` on that mirrored repository to create a **portable dump**
4. Well, that works until the original repo is still up and running.

*SIDE NOTE: I have been saving that daily backup file for years, but only now am I trying now to make any use of it and I have this problem. Which makes me think back about **making restores instead of backups***

Comment: Turns out Assembla can actually make sense of that Origo backup file. So all is good. I did try out the svnsync option and it also turned out to be quite fast and workable, though the dump file is about 150% larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it really backup of FS-tree of repo, you can **only**

- Install local SVN
- Restore files (directories?) from archive over empty repository location
- If all OK (repositories are reacheable and reabable) - create dump, which Assembla-interface can accept

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question. That is what I was expecting too. Though, it seems that somehow Assembla managed to import it, though probably not through the svnadmin load command.

Answer (score 1):

For origo repository after you extract the nightly dump use **Subversion 1.6.5** on linux to create a dump file  - "svnadmin dump ...". Then you can use "svnadmin load  .." to a local repository or use the dump for assembla.